# Mockito.invokeMethod: Can I pass an implemenation of a functional interface as an argument?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have a private method that I'm trying to test using powermock. The method parameters are a functional interface and an object. As per the docs, Whitebox.invokeMethod only accepts objects as parameters. Is there some sort of trick to pass an implementation of a functional interface?

ie

```
Object[] arguments = new Object[]{WarehouseOrderFieldFormattingProcessor::process, warehouseOrderEntity};
Whitebox.invokeMethod(processor, "processEntity", arguments);
```

The above snippet would be ideal but it doesn't compile because method references, and I'm pretty sure all implementations of functional interfaces, aren't objects.

**Edit:**

The declaration of the method I'm trying to pass:

```
public WarehouseOrderProcessorResult process(WarehouseOrderEntity entity, Configuration config) throws Exception {...}
```

The declaration of the method I'm trying to invoke:

```
private void processEntity(ProcessEntityFunc processLambda, WarehouseOrderEntity entity) throws Exception {...}
```

And the Functional Interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ProcessEntityFunc {
    WarehouseOrderProcessorResult process(WarehouseOrderEntity entity, Configuration config) throws Exception; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not right about method references and implementations of functional interfaces, you can put lambda to array:

```
Object myObject = new Object();
Consumer<Object> consumer = (Object item) -> System.out.println("Hello world");
Object[] arguments = new Object[]{consumer, myObject};
```

**EDIT:**

As you are trying to invoke non-static method you should create instance of `WarehouseOrderFieldFormattingProcessor`, then assign method reference to variable with type of your functional interface `ProcessEntityFunc` and only then pass it to array:

```
WarehouseOrderFieldFormattingProcessor warehouseOrderFieldFormattingProcessor = new WarehouseOrderFieldFormattingProcessor();
ProcessEntityFunc testFunction = warehouseOrderFieldFormattingProcessor::process;
Object[] arguments = new Object[]{testFunction, warehouseOrderEntity};
Whitebox.invokeMethod(processor, "processEntity", arguments);
```

Comment: And can you please show me functional interface that your tested method accept?